# Identifying grid in image and removing it

Tags: image-processing

I have images with some different objects on it and I have a specific backgound on it, it is a grid: [image]

It can be colored to a different color, but still with that grid. 
I want to find shapes of objects on that image, if I do it, that grid will give me many noise as a result. Could you please suggest me how to get rid of that noise or grid from image, if every image has such a grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1a) If the grid is of similar color as your object behind the 'grid', you can use Hough Transform (to detect edges and remove edges at 45 degrees and -45 degrees).

1b) If the grid is of different color, you can just remove anything with that color range.

2) You will then need to apply a texture synthesis algorithm (which i assume, after removing the 
45/-45 degree edges, you will see a tremendous amount of gaps) to fill the gaps.

Quick/Brief Reference:

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform

[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_synthesis

Comment: What if the colors (background) can be different in different places? some place is colored blue, other colored to white-like (as you see on image above) ? the option 1b requires to know that only one color is exactly there.

Comment: Then, i would proceed for the edge detection option(either by gradients or hough transform), since your grid has a fairly high number of chance of containing a set of strong edges. Other wise, you could proceed by searching for 'diamond' shape objects.

Comment: Searching for edges is good idea, but how then to distinguish those edges that are parts of some text or object above that background?

Comment: i assume the edges from the grid are approx. 45  degrees, based on that assumption, you can filter those out using houghtransform